# Не видит класс/файл Symfony 4

Tags: php, mvc, symfony, controller

Изучаю `Symfony`, в папке `Controller` хочу создать еще одну папку `Admin` для выведения туда контроллеров связанных с админкой. Получаю вот такую ошибку :

> The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\Admin\AdminsController"
>   to be defined in file
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\ibb\vendor\composer/../../src\Controller\Admin\AdminsController.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ibb\config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\ibb\config/services.yaml").

Файл `services.yml` методом "тыка" крутил - не помогло. Вот файл :

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

`routes.yml` :

```
admin:
    path: ibb/ttg.{_format}
    controller: App\Controller\Admin\AdminsController::entrance
    defaults:
        _format: html
```

Что нужно сделать что бы `autoloader` начал видеть эту поддиректорию?

Comment: namespace контроллера правильный? `App\Controller\Admin`

Comment: Покажи файл AdminsController.php
Скорее всего namespace неверный или имя файла/класса.

Comment: @ArtemyLapko все же очевидно `The file was found but the class was not in it` - namespace

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте учитывать директории в папке src/Controller, добавив /*:

`App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']`